# why is my hover image always smaller than my cover image in wordpress (kadence blocks with custom css)

Tags: css, wordpress

beginner here trying to set up a website for my company with no background in development. would like to ask for help for one issue in particular. i am trying to create a hover effect on my images where the image changes if you hover over it.

i found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzA_biT0DaA) which gave me a custom css code block to put in,

```
.custom-cover:hover .custom-image {
    opacity: 1;
}
.custom-image {
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

this helped a lot and it worked to achieve the effect, but my problem is that the cover image is always bigger than the custom image in front even though i ensured that they are the same size when uploading. i cannot drag or resize the image using the block editor either

any help would be appreciated! i just want to make the custom cover and custom image fully align. thank you very much

Comment: As far as CSS goes, it's very hard to predict what exactly is causing the wrong styling without looking in the browsers devtools. The C in CSS stands for "cascading", so styles defined on a more general level apply to your concrete elements